# How can I create custom email

Tags: email

My domain is hosted at Godaddy and my project is at Digitalocean.
I want more than 15 custom emails, I know Godaddy offers email services but it is a little expensive for me. What I want is another services who offers create emails without transfer my domain name from Godaddy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always purchase separate email service from MXRoute or Zoho, then please make sure you edit your DNS settings and point to correct settings.